# Unicode keyboard on Mac OSX mess VIM editor badly

Tags: vim, unicode

When I using Unicode keyboard on Mac OSX (Vietnamese in my case) while using normal mode VIM and try to type into the editor (starting with `i` and then some combination to produce non-ascii characters), it results in a lot of weird changes in the editor like lines of character appears at the end of the editor. Undo multiple times wouldn't restore the text back to what it should be. The problem happens on both MacVim and VIM inside Terminal. I've been experiencing it for 7.3 and 7.4 as of now.

Is there a way to stop VIM from behave like that, like ignore special (non ascii) characters?

Comment: Train yourself to get more self control and focus.

Comment: I see, You can train yourself to work around software bug. You don't need any software bug fix or any customization :D

Comment: Where is the software bug, here? *You* forgot to do something so PEBKAC.

Comment: VIM is responding to unicode character with dangerous changes, so I would say it's a bug. And well, if it something can be fixed with a configuration, or a patch, I would rather use that than train myself into non practical thing. You are human, you suppose to forget something now and then. Or may be, you are not?

Comment: May I remind you that you didn't even provide any screenshot or whatever showing the damage or a list of "unicode characters" causing that damage? What the hell is a "unicode character" anyway? `A`, `…`, `げ`…? Does it happen in insert mode? Normal mode? Another one? GUI Vim or Vim? What version? What terminal emulator if any? Does it happen with and without your config? So far, we only have a random guy on the internet complaining about mysterious changes when he forgets something. Barring any more precise info, that's not a bug but simple user error.

Comment: Okay, I edited my question with more details. Though I have no interest in arguing whether it's a bug or a *designed feature* of VIM. I just want to get it work in a sane way.

Comment: Sounds more like a terminal issue than a bug in Vim. You're going to have to be more specific about what happens (an exact input and resulting screen shot would be nice.) Something that *we* could reproduce.

Comment: This happen with a localized Input Sources being used. I think any one who ever happened to use localized Input Sources and VIM at same time should experience the similar issue, in which VIM execute special command when a unicode character being submitted. I tried with vanilla VIM before and it has the same behavior.